# Return array of names from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, filter

I know how to loop through an object and print out an array of values I want, but I'm having trouble figuring out printing it in the order that I want .

**The question is: **

Given a collection of game outcome records, determine who all the players are by returning an array of their names.

The array should be ordered by how the names are encountered.

Example Input:

```
[
  { winner: 'Alishah', loser: 'Bob',    loser_points: 3 },
  { winner: 'Maria',   loser: 'Xu Jin', loser_points: 1 },
  { winner: 'Elise',   loser: 'Bob',    loser_points: 2 },
  { winner: 'Elise',   loser: 'Maria',  loser_points: 4 },
  { winner: 'Alishah', loser: 'Maria',  loser_points: 2 },
  { winner: 'Maria',   loser: 'Xu Jin', loser_points: 3 },
  { winner: 'Xu Jin',  loser: 'Elise',  loser_points: 2 }
]
```

Expected Result:

['Alishah', 'Bob', 'Maria', 'Xu Jin', 'Elise']

**The code I have so far: **

```js
let data = [
  { winner: 'Alishah', loser: 'Bob',    loser_points: 3 },
  { winner: 'Maria',   loser: 'Xu Jin', loser_points: 1 },
  { winner: 'Elise',   loser: 'Bob',    loser_points: 2 },
  { winner: 'Elise',   loser: 'Maria',  loser_points: 4 },
  { winner: 'Alishah', loser: 'Maria',  loser_points: 2 },
  { winner: 'Maria',   loser: 'Xu Jin', loser_points: 3 },
  { winner: 'Xu Jin',  loser: 'Elise',  loser_points: 2 }
];

   
console.log(main(data));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for this:

```js
let data = [
  { winner: 'Alishah', loser: 'Bob',    loser_points: 3 },
  { winner: 'Maria',   loser: 'Xu Jin', loser_points: 1 },
  { winner: 'Elise',   loser: 'Bob',    loser_points: 2 },
  { winner: 'Elise',   loser: 'Maria',  loser_points: 4 },
  { winner: 'Alishah', loser: 'Maria',  loser_points: 2 },
  { winner: 'Maria',   loser: 'Xu Jin', loser_points: 3 },
  { winner: 'Xu Jin',  loser: 'Elise',  loser_points: 2 }
];

const res = [...new Set(data.flatMap(x=>[x.winner, x.loser]))]
console.log( res )
```

**Explanation:**

- Using `.flatMap()` method we will first get an array of arrays. Here the inner array will be array of `winner` & `loser` names.
- Then we will flatten the array to get a single array of all player's name.
- And finally using `[...new Set(array)]` we will get distinct names in the array to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get names and **remove duplicates**

`Array.reduce()` iterates over the array. So you can push all `winner`s and `loser`s to the initial empty array.

Then you can create a new `Set`. This way, you can remove duplicates (since all items are `string`). After that, you can convert it back to array by using the `spread syntax`: `[...new Set(array)]`

```js
const arr = [
  { winner: 'Alishah', loser: 'Bob',    loser_points: 3 },
  { winner: 'Maria',   loser: 'Xu Jin', loser_points: 1 },
  { winner: 'Elise',   loser: 'Bob',    loser_points: 2 },
  { winner: 'Elise',   loser: 'Maria',  loser_points: 4 },
  { winner: 'Alishah', loser: 'Maria',  loser_points: 2 },
  { winner: 'Maria',   loser: 'Xu Jin', loser_points: 3 },
  { winner: 'Xu Jin',  loser: 'Elise',  loser_points: 2 }
]

const names = [...new Set(arr.reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, cur.winner, cur.loser], []))]

console.log(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
console.clear();

"use strict";

const score = [
  { winner: 'Alishah', loser: 'Bob',    loser_points: 3 },
  { winner: 'Maria',   loser: 'Xu Jin', loser_points: 1 },
  { winner: 'Elise',   loser: 'Bob',    loser_points: 2 },
  { winner: 'Elise',   loser: 'Maria',  loser_points: 4 },
  { winner: 'Alishah', loser: 'Maria',  loser_points: 2 },
  { winner: 'Maria',   loser: 'Xu Jin', loser_points: 3 },
  { winner: 'Xu Jin',  loser: 'Elise',  loser_points: 2 }
]

function reduce(coll, {winner, loser}) {
  if (!coll.includes(winner)) {
    coll.push(winner)
  }
  if (!coll.includes(loser)) {
    coll.push(loser)
  }
  return coll;
}

var players = score.reduce(reduce, [])
console.log(players)
```

Comment: This is not matching the expected result OP has shared: `['Alishah', 'Bob', 'Maria', 'Xu Jin', 'Elise']`

Answer (score 0):

Looking your code and your expected result I think you're missing to push into `arr` also the `looser` name. To fix it my favourite approach is the `reduce` method of js array:

```js
const arr = outcomes.reduce((completeList,{winner, looser}) => {
    const extraNames = [winner, looser]
        .filter(x => !completeList.includes(x));
    return [
        ...completeList,
        ...extraNames
    ];
}, []);
```

Comment: This produces duplicates, each name should only show up once.

Answer (score 0):

```
var players = collection.reduce((acc, player) => {
    if(!acc.inStore[player.winner]) {
        acc.players.push(player.winner)
        acc.inStore[player.winner] = true
    }
    if(!acc.inStore[player.loser]) {
        acc.players.push(player.loser)
        acc.inStore[player.loser] = true
    }
    return acc;
}, {players: [], inStore: {}}).players

// ["Alishah", "Bob", "Maria", "Xu Jin", "Elise"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using map and filter

```js
let array = [
  { winner: 'Alishah', loser: 'Bob',    loser_points: 3 },
  { winner: 'Maria',   loser: 'Xu Jin', loser_points: 1 },
  { winner: 'Elise',   loser: 'Bob',    loser_points: 2 },
  { winner: 'Elise',   loser: 'Maria',  loser_points: 4 },
  { winner: 'Alishah', loser: 'Maria',  loser_points: 2 },
  { winner: 'Maria',   loser: 'Xu Jin', loser_points: 3 },
  { winner: 'Xu Jin',  loser: 'Elise',  loser_points: 2 }
];

let winners = array.map(i => i.winner).filter((x, i, a) => a.indexOf(x) == i)
console.log(winners);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const outcomes = [
  { winner: 'Alishah', loser: 'Bob',    loser_points: 3 },
  { winner: 'Maria',   loser: 'Xu Jin', loser_points: 1 },
  { winner: 'Elise',   loser: 'Bob',    loser_points: 2 },
  { winner: 'Elise',   loser: 'Maria',  loser_points: 4 },
  { winner: 'Alishah', loser: 'Maria',  loser_points: 2 },
  { winner: 'Maria',   loser: 'Xu Jin', loser_points: 3 },
  { winner: 'Xu Jin',  loser: 'Elise',  loser_points: 2 }
];

const result = outcomes.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if(!acc.includes(cur.winner))
  acc.push(cur.winner);
  if(!acc.includes(cur.loser))
  acc.push(cur.loser);
  return acc;
}, []).join(",");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is also not matching the expected result OP has shared: `['Alishah', 'Bob', 'Maria', 'Xu Jin', 'Elise']`

Comment: @palaѕн Good catch.